# Removing Extra Spaces in a String Using Loops

Tags: python-3.x

I just started learning python very recently,
and I was given this exercise to remove extra spaces (as in more than one) in a string using loops.

My attempt is first to label all the indexes of the spaces in the string,
as below

```
string = 'I wanna   be    your      number   one   '
i = 0
list1 = []
for space_index in string:
    space_index = string.find(' ', i, len(string))
    list1.append(space_index)
    i = space_index
    i += 1

print(list1)
```

The output looks like the following with every number appears twice except -1

```
[1, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 32, 33, 34, 38, 39, 40, -1, 1, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 32, 33, 34, 38, 39, 40]
```

I hope someone could help point out the mistake I made that induced the duplication in the list 
Also if there are ways using find to remove the extra spaces please share.
(I've found method replacing '  ' with ' ' which is direct and efficient, but for this exercise I want to use find and index)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The code is somewhat confusing. With `for space_index in string:`, you are iterating over every character in `string`. However, on each iteration you overwrite `space_index` with the result of `find`. The usage of `i` is not very clear either... What exactly are you trying to achieve here? What were you expecting to get in `list1`, the list of indices where `string` contains a whitespace?

Comment: @jdehesa Yes I was thinking about making a list of space indexes with `list1`, and then use another loop to eliminate the spaces when they are sequenced... Please share your thoughts on more optimal ways of doing it 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the list of all whitespaces using a loop and `find`, a `for` loop may not be the right choice, since that will always go through every character in the string (instead of "jumping to the next whitespace"). You can however use a `while` loop like this:

```
string = 'I wanna   be    your      number   one   '
# List of indices of whitespaces
list1 = []
# We start searching from index 0
i = 0
# While find() does not return -1
while i >= 0:
    # Look for the next space
    i = string.find(' ', i)  # Third argument can be omitted to search until the end
    # If a valid index was found
    if i >= 0:
        # Add the index to the list
        list1.append(i)
        # In the next iteration we continue searching from the next index
        i += 1
print(list1)
# [1, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 32, 33, 34, 38, 39, 40]
```

A common method to do this in Python more succinctly would be with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this:

```
list1 = [i for i, c in enumerate(string) if c == ' ']
```

About your problem in general, the most common way for solving that would be with a regular expression, but that is a rather advanced topic. You can try to solve as you are currently thinking, hopefully it should not be too hard. Another possible alternative way you can solve it is having a list of characters, initially empty, and iterate through every character (like `for char in string:`), then you add each character to the list unless it is a whitespace and the previous character was also a whitespace. You can convert the list of characters into a string with `''.join(my_list_of_characters)`.

Note that one tricky aspect of this problem is the ending of the string. The sequence of whitespaces at the end, should be reduced to a single one, or removed altogether (because no other word follows)? You can think of different strategies to deal with this.

Comment: Thanks @jdehesa ! I actually have thought hard about how to do the method you mentioned (`for char in string`) but I stuck at how to define "the previous character was also a whitespace", could you help shed some light on this? Thanks again!

Comment: @HannahChou The easiest thing is to define a variable before the loop, e.g. `prev_char = ''`, then if you do `for char in string:` you can do something like `if not (char == ' ' and prev_char == ' '):`. At the end of the loop body, you just do `prev_char = char` so the next iteration it will have the previous character. See if you can figure it out with that, otherwise leave another comment and I'll add the whole `for` loop to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @jdehesa's comment already pointed out, the duplication of the space indexes in your output comes from the fact that you're iterating over each character in your string but not using the characters themselves to identify spaces, so here, you for loop will continue despite the fact that you have already found all spaces in the string.

To get the list of space indexes, I would probably suggest something like this if you're bound to using a for loop:

```
list_of_spaces = []

for character_id in range(len(string)):
    if string[character_id] == " ":
        list_of_spaces.append(character_id)
    else:
        continue

print(list_of_spaces)
# > [1, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 32, 33, 34, 38, 39, 40]
```

Another way to do so if you want to use the `.find()` method and a while loop could be:

```
list_of_spaces = []

character_id = 0
while character_id < len(string):
    space_id = string.find(' ', character_id, len(string))
    list_of_spaces.append(space_id)
    character_id = space_id+1

print(list_of_spaces)
# > [1, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 32, 33, 34, 38, 39, 40]
```

Finally, a nicer way to delete spaces can be achieved by using the regex library:

```
import re

string = 'I wanna   be    your      number   one   '
re.sub(' +', ' ', string)

# > 'I wanna be your number one'
```

Comment: The `while` loop in the second snippet loops indefinitely when the string does not finish with a whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution that came to my mind is:

```
string = 'I wanna   be    your      number   one   '
new_string = " ".join(string.split())
```

- `list_of_words = string.split()` splits `string` into a list where each word is a list item.
- `new_string = " ".join(list_of_words)` joins all items of `list_of_words` into a string, using a space as separator